# Creating a user profile page using a database

Tags: c#, winforms

I am doing a simple project for school where I have to create a login form and make it so when a person logs in it then shows their profile with all their user information. So how would I code the textboxes in windows forms C# so when a person logs in the textboxes show information gathered from database of person who just logged in.

This is the code for the login form.

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\RAV21001310\\OneDrive\\Database1.accdb;";

        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

        command.Connection = connection;

        command.CommandText = "select * from tblUser where Username= '"+username.Text+"' and Password= '"+password.Text+"'";

        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        int count = 0;

        while (reader.Read())

        {

            count = count + 1;

        }

        if (count == 1)

        {

            MessageBox.Show("Username and password is correct");

            var profile = new profile();

        }

        if (count > 1)

        {

            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate username and password");

        }

        else

        {

            MessageBox.Show("Username or password incorrect");

        }

        connection.Close();
```

Comment: First off, the DB connection string is opening you up to SQL injection... always use parameters to pass in the username, never string concatenation.

Comment: To start with, read up on the `IDisposable` interface and the `using` statement. Many of the objects you are utilizing are disposable and should be disposed of (preferably using `using`)

Comment: Since it's WinForms, what I'd do is create a form with your profile data laid out and empty. Put a `[Logon]` button on that form. Now create a second form to use for the login. When the button is pressed, bring the form up with `var lf = new LoginForm(); if (lf.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.Ok) { /*code*/}`. In the `code` section, put your data access code and fill in the original form's fields

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, always use parameters in your query strings. Also, since OleDbDataReader is forward reading only, what I would do is create a new user and add to a list for each record returned. Then, if you only get one record, use that user data to populate the form. One other major flaw in your code... You are storing passwords as plain text in the database. The best practice is to encrypt/hash the password using one-way encryption and only store the hash in the database. Everytime the user enters a password at login, hash it using the same algorithm and compare it against the hash stored in the DB.

Here's an example incorporating `Using` (suggested by @Flydog57) and `Parameters`. But I'm not showing how to hash and store encrypted passwords.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\RAV21001310\\OneDrive\\Database1.accdb;")) 
        {
            connection.Open();
            
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password", connection)) 
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username.text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password.text);
                
                using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) 
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    
                    List<User> UserList = new List<User>();
                    while (reader.Read()) 
                    {
                        count = count + 1;
                        
                        User user = new User() {
                            Username = reader.GetString(1),
                            FirstName = reader.GetString(2),
                            LastName = reader.GetString(3),
                            DateCreated = reader.GetDateTime(4)
                        };
                        
                        UserList.Add(user);
                    }

                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        //Alert User
                        MessageBox.Show("Username and password is correct");

                        //Create an instance of the ProfileForm and populated it with the User data.
                        var ProfileForm pf = new ProfileForm(UserList[0]);

                        //Show the Profile Form as a modal window.
                        pf.ShowDialog();
                    }

                    if (count > 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate username and password");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Username or password incorrect");
                    }
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}

//This is a class to hold user data.
public class User {
    public string Username { get; set; } = "";
    public string Password { get; set; } = "";
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "";
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "";
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

This is a quick sample of the code-behind for a "ProfileForm". When you verify the user is authenticated, then create an instance of the ProfileForm, populate it with the userdata, then show the form to the user. There are many other ways to populate a profile form and handle updates to user data, this is just one example.

```
public class ProfileForm : Form
{
    public User User
    {
        get 
        { 
            //When you get the User, update all the user data from text boxes.
            User.FirstName = firstnameTextBox.Text;
            User.LastName = lastnameTextBox.Text;

            //return the newly updated User variable.
            return User;
        }
        set
        {
            //When we write new data to the form User variable,
            //populate each relevant text box on the form.
            usernameTextBox.Text = User.Username;
            firstnameTextBox.Text = User.FirstName;
            lastnameTextBox.Text = User.LastName; 
        }
    }
    
    public ProfileForm(User User) {
        this.User = User;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks but how would I populate the textboxes in the profile page with data from the user? Sorry I'm just really new at windows forms and I can't find anything online.

Comment: Your question is becoming very broad. I updated my answer with an example of what a "ProfileForm" code-behind might look like. Please note I moved the `User` class outside the `Program` class. You need to try to apply the example to your project and then report back, or ask a new question, with any _specific_ problems you encounter.